# How can I get the expiration date of an intermediate certificate and trusted root certificate by C# code?

Tags: c#

How can I get the expiration date of an intermediate certificate and trusted [root certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate) by C# code?

I need to get data about a certificate in Internet Option (-> content -> certificates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [X509Certificate.GetExpirationDateString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getexpirationdatestring.aspx).

To get the certificate, use:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName,
    "name",
    false);

X509Certificate2 cert = certs[0];

cert.GetExpirationDateString();
```

I have not included exception handling and checks for clarity.